# C# Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'short' for item value

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am learning C# and keep getting an error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'short'".

In Microsoft SQL Server where my database is, U_Weeks_In_Month is defined as smallint. What do I need to do to solve this error?

I tried to use short.Parse just like in the year textfields but this does not work for the item, i.e

```
U_Weeks_In_Month = short.Parse(item.WeekNumber),
```

Any solution?

My code is :

```
var weekInfos = SAPUtility.GetWeekInfo(dateTimePicker1.Value, 52);

// Create object
foreach (var item in weekInfos)
{
    // Get new code
    var newWeeklyCode = weeklyPeriodService.GenerateSAPCode();

    var weeklyPeriodAdd =
        new WeeklyPeriod
        {
            Code = newWeeklyCode,
            Name = newWeeklyCode,
            U_Tax_Year = short.Parse(txt_tax_year.Text),
            U_Month = item.Month.ToString(),
            U_Pay_Process_Status = "N",
            U_Payroll_Year = short.Parse(txt_tax_year.Text),
            U_Weeks_In_Month = item.WeekNumber,
            U_Starting_date = item.FirstDayOfWeek,
            U_Ending_date = item.LastDayOfWeek,
        };

    // Save record
    weeklyPeriodService.AddWeeklyPeriod(weeklyPeriodAdd);
}
```

Comment: can you provide the code of your class? What type your fields are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you just need:

```
U_Weeks_In_Month = (short) item.WeekNumber
```

An alternative is to change your `WeekNumber` property to `short` to start with.

Additionally, I'd pull the parsing of `txt_tax_year.Text` *outside* the loop:

```
short taxYear = short.Parse(txt_tax_year.Text);
foreach (var item in weekInfos)
{
    // Use taxYear in here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the item eg:
 U_Weeks_In_Month = (short)item.WeekNumber,

But I would check why item.WeekNumber is an integer and correct it (assuming the code is yours).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `item.WeekNumber` is of type `int`. In that case compiler is giving the right error. You should be using `short.Parse` or `short.TryParse` if you not sure that parsing will succeed.